# python regex - find html tags with specific class

Tags: python, regex

i want to write a regular expression that extracts the text out of all html elements of class important from that string:

```html
text = """Lorem ipsum dolor <b>sit</b> amet, <b class="important">consectetur adipiscing</b> elit,\ 
sed do eiusmod <span id="note">tempor incididunt ut</span> <div>labore <strong class="important">\
et dolore magna</strong> aliqua.</div> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco."""
```

do you have idea for a simple and short answer?
thank you!

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Use either beautiful soup to parse the html file and extract the required content. Their documentation is really easy to understand, and the library itself easy to use.

Comment: Don't use regex for html parsing. It WILL give you headaches. Comment #1 above hints at why it's a bad idea, comment #2 above suggests a solution you should definitely consider.

Answer (score 1):

try using this regex pattern

```
<[^>]*class="important"[^>]*>[^>]*<\/[^>]*>
```

if you want to remove the tags you can use regex substitute with the pattern:

```
<\/{0,1}[^>]*>
```

if you want to make patterns try out https://regexr.com its a great site that highlight the matches making things easier. please do mark as answer if this helps you.

Comment: re.sub(pattern, new_string, input_string)
in pattern is your regex pattern
new_string is what you want to replace with
input_string should be your text variable in this case

Comment: if you want to remove the html tags <>, try:
output = re.sub(r"<\/{0,1}[^>]*>","",input_string)
here we substitute the matched with empty string to remove it.